# Quoting parameter in pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and I found `quotechar` and quoting parameters in it,

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=', ' , quotechar='"', quoting=0)
```

what is the exact use of these parameters? I checked the documentation, but I can't comprehend it.

Answer (score 5):

it's for handling multi string data:

```
In [39]:
data = {"strings": ["string", "string,string"],
        "int": np.arange(2),
        "float": np.random.randn(2)}
​
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

Out[39]:
      float  int        strings
0  0.116076    0         string
1 -0.316229    1  string,string

In [40]:    
df.to_csv(quotechar="'")

Out[40]:
",float,int,strings\n0,0.11607600924932446,0,string\n1,-0.31622948240636567,1,'string,string'\n"
```

You can see that the `string,string` gets quoted to:

```
'string,string'
```

when writing to a csv

Whilst the first single string is left alone.

The default quote char is double quotes:

```
In [41]:
df.to_csv()

Out[41]:
',float,int,strings\n0,0.11607600924932446,0,string\n1,-0.31622948240636567,1,"string,string"\n'
```

the multi-string entry is written out as:

```
"string,string"
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV can just use a comma to separate fields, but if you have a field with a comma in it, to avoid that becoming two fields, the whole field needs to be enclosed, usually with double quotes. Some CSV dialects enclose every field in double quotes but that wastes space.

The options for quoting are QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3)

quoting=0 means minimal quoting so **only** a field that contains a separator will be enclosed.  It will look something like this.

```
Name, Address, Field
Ai Weiwei, "Berlin, Germany", Visual Arts
"Jagger, Mick", London, Music
```

Note also that your example contains a two character separator, sep=', ' (a comma and space) so I used that above but it also wastes space in the file.