# how to read csv file with commas within double quote using pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, separator

I have a dataset looks like this on wordpad.

"state","industry","2000","2005"

"A","art,music",2934,2454

"B","farm",3949,2343

And I want to read this on python like this.

| "state" | "industry" | "2000" | "2005" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | "art,music" | 2934 | 2454 |
| "B" | "farm" | 3949 | 2343 |

I tried the codes below.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, filename), engine='python', sep=',' , quoting=3)
```

this casts an error "ParserError: Expected 6 fields in line 8, saw 8"

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, filename), engine='python', sep='",' , quoting=3)
```

this puts all the numbers in a same cell.

I read a lot of posts asking similar question, but mine is a bit different from then because 1) I have a data which contains commas within double quotes and 2) employment numbers are not quoted.

How can I handle it? Help appreciated!

Comment: `quoting=3` tells pandas that nothing in the csv file is quoted, which isn't the case for this file.  Use `quoting=0` instead.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357614/494134

Comment: I don't understand why you want those extra quotes in the strings. By default, read_csv would read strings which would would see as, for instance, `state` (5 characters). But you want quotes around them? The python literal would be `'"state"'` (7 characters).

Answer (score 1):

The default parameters to `read_csv` should work

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# for test
csv = io.StringIO('''\
"state","industry","2000","2005"
"A","art,music",2934,2454
"B","farm",3949,2343''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

output

```
  state   industry  2000  2005
0     A  art,music  2934  2454
1     B       farm  3949  2343
state       object
industry    object
2000         int64
2005         int64
```