# Python/Pandas adding quotes to string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using Python/Pandas to edit a csv file created by another program.

One of the columns contains values contained within duoble quotes:

> "RGB(0,255,255)"

for example.
This is just how it is output by the program and I need to preserve these quotes in order for it to be read back into the program once I have edited it. Currently when I try to exporting the edited data frame to a .csv, the quotes around the values dissapear. so the values look like this:

> RGB(0,255,255)

I tried adding quotes manually to the values in the column before exporting, but now the .csv file has triple quotes so looks like this:

> """RGB(0,255,255)"""

I'm not doing anything with this particular column, I literally just need it to retain the format it had before being read into my Python script. I'm assuiming there are some arguments in either my read_csv or to_csv  commands but I'm not sure where to start. Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: If anyone else stumbles across this - I've found a temporary solution - I'm adding a wilcard character (~) to the string. Then after exporting the csv I'm replacing all instances of ~ with ". Probably not the most elegant solution but it works at the moment

Comment: Could something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344241/quoting-parameter-in-pandas-read-csv?msclkid=1aad8c6bcedb11ecbca00ac95898af36) work (the different `quoting` options are given in the answer by InnocentBystander)?

Answer (score 0):

Save the DataFrame as a pickle instead.

```
df.to_pickle('test.pkl')

# To load the dataframe again
df = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')
```

This will preserve the structures!